# Magento2 enterprise cloud error

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise

```
The requested URL was rejected.

For additional information, please contact support and provide this reference ID:

c1067ccab6a166c723762ea0ae08206ab2c6c154204b56c1dafd9b4d1e7e6f82
```

I am getting above mentioned error while submitting form in arabic content. I don't know how to resolve this issue. Can someone guide me?

Is fastly causing the issue.

Comment: You have to checck the log at cloud server

Comment: You have to check the log at cloud server in var/log/report/  and var/log/ folder